How to run the build command before the build on Digital Ocean App Platform
I need the json key file to configure my google cloud storage credentials in my settings.py (Django app)
GS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "static/GCS_key_api.json"

GS_PROJECT_ID = os.getenv('GS_PROJECT_ID')

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)`

Here the logs of the build on App Plateofrm:
2024-05-19T09:24:41.171400485Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m git repo clone [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.171433696Z [34m│[0m [34m › fetching app source code[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.171437957Z [34m│[0m => Selecting branch "main"
2024-05-19T09:24:41.233929376Z [34m│[0m => Checking out commit "b0f8c02acbc8ef86ba30b50e4295f53a938aa584"
2024-05-19T09:24:41.237120654Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.239089601Z [34m│[0m [32m ✔ cloned repo to [35m/workspace[0m[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.317807317Z [34m╰────────────────────────────────────────╼[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.317827278Z 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.492647202Z [34m › configuring build-time app environment variables:[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.492841261Z      EMAIL_HOST_USER EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD GS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON STRIPE_API_KEY SECRET_KEY GS_BUCKET_NAME PUBLIC_GS_BUCKET_NAME EMAIL_HOST GS_PROJECT_ID DEBUG DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS EMAIL_PORT
2024-05-19T09:24:41.492854441Z 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.494640715Z [34m › configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.498131225Z    [34m│[0m bin/pre_build.sh
2024-05-19T09:24:41.498140596Z 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.567448183Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m buildpack detection [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.584376861Z [34m│[0m [34m › using Ubuntu 22.04 stack[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933275054Z [34m│[0m Detected the following buildpacks suitable to build your app:
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933296537Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933299356Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/python-appdetect  v0.0.3    
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933301358Z [34m│[0m    heroku/python                  v4.242.4  (Python)
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933303328Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/procfile          v0.0.4    (Procfile)
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933323594Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/custom            v0.1.2    (Custom Build Command)
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933326093Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933329053Z [34m│[0m For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933330985Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.933332932Z [34m│[0m    Python  v4.242.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-python
2024-05-19T09:24:41.936049330Z [34m╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╼[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:41.936066543Z 
2024-05-19T09:24:41.938555872Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m app build [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2024-05-19T09:24:42.018292005Z [34m│[0m -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.12.1
2024-05-19T09:24:42.018310379Z [34m│[0m        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
2024-05-19T09:24:42.293032467Z [34m│[0m -----> Installing python-3.12.1
2024-05-19T09:24:42.818026912Z [34m│[0m -----> Installing pip 23.3.2, setuptools 68.2.2 and wheel 0.42.0
2024-05-19T09:24:46.964311281Z [34m│[0m -----> Installing SQLite3
2024-05-19T09:24:52.791075033Z [34m│[0m -----> Installing requirements with pip
2024-05-19T09:24:53.117356368Z [34m│[0m        Ignoring backports.zoneinfo: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
2024-05-19T09:24:53.222480888Z [34m│[0m        Collecting asgiref==3.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.294707525Z [34m│[0m          Downloading asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.314619182Z [34m│[0m        Collecting cachetools==5.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.317834368Z [34m│[0m          Downloading cachetools-5.3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.337704757Z [34m│[0m        Collecting certifi==2024.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.340556975Z [34m│[0m          Downloading certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.418693714Z [34m│[0m        Collecting charset-normalizer==3.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.421683379Z [34m│[0m          Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.444156502Z [34m│[0m        Collecting dj-database-url==2.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.447250198Z [34m│[0m          Downloading dj_database_url-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.530217262Z [34m│[0m        Collecting Django==4.2.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.533818266Z [34m│[0m          Downloading Django-4.2.13-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.554788905Z [34m│[0m        Collecting django-storages==1.14.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.558583659Z [34m│[0m          Downloading django_storages-1.14.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (63 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.618830158Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-api-core==2.18.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.622818232Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google_api_core-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.694518597Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-auth==2.29.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.697554064Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google_auth-2.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.724608582Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-cloud-core==2.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.728167245Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google_cloud_core-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.775276739Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-cloud-storage==2.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.778224420Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google_cloud_storage-2.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.809871088Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-crc32c==1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
2024-05-19T09:24:53.813121887Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google-crc32c-1.5.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:53.819540157Z [34m│[0m          Installing build dependencies: started
2024-05-19T09:24:55.472206144Z [34m│[0m          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
2024-05-19T09:24:55.474196218Z [34m│[0m          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
2024-05-19T09:24:55.627798045Z [34m│[0m          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
2024-05-19T09:24:55.630556248Z [34m│[0m          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
2024-05-19T09:24:55.792748013Z [34m│[0m          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
2024-05-19T09:24:55.819072676Z [34m│[0m        Collecting google-resumable-media==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
2024-05-19T09:24:55.822516726Z [34m│[0m          Downloading google_resumable_media-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:55.843500843Z [34m│[0m        Collecting googleapis-common-protos==1.63.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
2024-05-19T09:24:55.845819671Z [34m│[0m          Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.63.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:55.866424610Z [34m│[0m        Collecting gunicorn==22.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
2024-05-19T09:24:55.868778369Z [34m│[0m          Downloading gunicorn-22.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:55.884073402Z [34m│[0m        Collecting idna==3.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
2024-05-19T09:24:55.886422924Z [34m│[0m          Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:55.909527092Z [34m│[0m        Collecting packaging==24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
2024-05-19T09:24:55.912518604Z [34m│[0m          Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.081004310Z [34m│[0m        Collecting pillow==10.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.084196591Z [34m│[0m          Downloading pillow-10.2.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.107233846Z [34m│[0m        Collecting proto-plus==1.23.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.109589938Z [34m│[0m          Downloading proto_plus-1.23.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.283023364Z [34m│[0m        Collecting protobuf==4.25.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.285960681Z [34m│[0m          Downloading protobuf-4.25.3-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (541 bytes)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.350920402Z [34m│[0m        Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.9.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.354188208Z [34m│[0m          Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.9-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.380867617Z [34m│[0m        Collecting pyasn1==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.383631019Z [34m│[0m          Downloading pyasn1-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.407054951Z [34m│[0m        Collecting pyasn1_modules==0.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.409992067Z [34m│[0m          Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.502557803Z [34m│[0m        Collecting pycryptodomex==3.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.505728319Z [34m│[0m          Downloading pycryptodomex-3.20.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.518587159Z [34m│[0m        Collecting pyzipper==0.3.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.523112664Z [34m│[0m          Downloading pyzipper-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.556243400Z [34m│[0m        Collecting requests==2.31.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 27))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.559324535Z [34m│[0m          Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.576978289Z [34m│[0m        Collecting rsa==4.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.579497201Z [34m│[0m          Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.594094995Z [34m│[0m        Collecting sqlparse==0.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.597292732Z [34m│[0m          Downloading sqlparse-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.732312155Z [34m│[0m        Collecting stripe==8.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.737042324Z [34m│[0m          Downloading stripe-8.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.756424353Z [34m│[0m        Collecting typing_extensions==4.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.759648205Z [34m│[0m          Downloading typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:56.799646939Z [34m│[0m        Collecting urllib3==2.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
2024-05-19T09:24:56.802683576Z [34m│[0m          Downloading urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.213544280Z [34m│[0m        Downloading asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.216733654Z [34m│[0m        Downloading cachetools-5.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.220278216Z [34m│[0m        Downloading certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.224661004Z [34m│[0m        Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (141 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.228638126Z [34m│[0m        Downloading dj_database_url-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.7 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.232422406Z [34m│[0m        Downloading Django-4.2.13-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.285460412Z [34m│[0m        Downloading django_storages-1.14.2-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.289743235Z [34m│[0m        Downloading google_api_core-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.293400065Z [34m│[0m        Downloading google_auth-2.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (189 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.297292021Z [34m│[0m        Downloading google_cloud_core-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.300457909Z [34m│[0m        Downloading google_cloud_storage-2.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.304306243Z [34m│[0m        Downloading google_resumable_media-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.307958594Z [34m│[0m        Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.63.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.311738820Z [34m│[0m        Downloading gunicorn-22.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.315192373Z [34m│[0m        Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.319029520Z [34m│[0m        Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.324054009Z [34m│[0m        Downloading pillow-10.2.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.345609792Z [34m│[0m        Downloading proto_plus-1.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.348759056Z [34m│[0m        Downloading protobuf-4.25.3-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (294 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.353642984Z [34m│[0m        Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.9-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.366846524Z [34m│[0m        Downloading pyasn1-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (85 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.370285731Z [34m│[0m        Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.374664948Z [34m│[0m        Downloading pycryptodomex-3.20.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.401168909Z [34m│[0m        Downloading pyzipper-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.404402964Z [34m│[0m        Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.407345979Z [34m│[0m        Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.410529181Z [34m│[0m        Downloading sqlparse-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.518159183Z [34m│[0m        Downloading stripe-8.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.525380535Z [34m│[0m        Downloading typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.528484218Z [34m│[0m        Downloading urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
2024-05-19T09:24:57.636929492Z [34m│[0m        Building wheels for collected packages: google-crc32c
2024-05-19T09:24:57.637808258Z [34m│[0m          Building wheel for google-crc32c (pyproject.toml): started
2024-05-19T09:24:58.072771654Z [34m│[0m          Building wheel for google-crc32c (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
2024-05-19T09:24:58.073101034Z [34m│[0m          Created wheel for google-crc32c: filename=google_crc32c-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl size=13026 sha256=0ac587824e1ec57e785ce95ffb26ea7d6d00193f41759991eaaa9402211af4d1
2024-05-19T09:24:58.073117621Z [34m│[0m          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-y96jty07/wheels/40/b9/2e/089df51c5e6f7cda282c650457a1d9a7a55bf6386d8de8bf3d
2024-05-19T09:24:58.075203614Z [34m│[0m        Successfully built google-crc32c
2024-05-19T09:24:58.229077911Z [34m│[0m        Installing collected packages: urllib3, typing_extensions, sqlparse, pycryptodomex, pyasn1, psycopg2-binary, protobuf, pillow, packaging, idna, google-crc32c, charset-normalizer, certifi, cachetools, asgiref, rsa, requests, pyzipper, pyasn1_modules, proto-plus, gunicorn, googleapis-common-protos, google-resumable-media, Django, stripe, google-auth, django-storages, dj-database-url, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-storage
2024-05-19T09:25:02.888422677Z [34m│[0m        Successfully installed Django-4.2.13 asgiref-3.8.1 cachetools-5.3.3 certifi-2024.2.2 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 dj-database-url-2.1.0 django-storages-1.14.2 google-api-core-2.18.0 google-auth-2.29.0 google-cloud-core-2.4.1 google-cloud-storage-2.16.0 google-crc32c-1.5.0 google-resumable-media-2.7.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.63.0 gunicorn-22.0.0 idna-3.6 packaging-24.0 pillow-10.2.0 proto-plus-1.23.0 protobuf-4.25.3 psycopg2-binary-2.9.9 pyasn1-0.6.0 pyasn1_modules-0.4.0 pycryptodomex-3.20.0 pyzipper-0.3.6 requests-2.31.0 rsa-4.9 sqlparse-0.5.0 stripe-8.9.0 typing_extensions-4.10.0 urllib3-2.2.1
2024-05-19T09:25:03.654497143Z [34m│[0m -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798153050Z [34m│[0m        Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798191580Z [34m│[0m          File "/workspace/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798195684Z [34m│[0m            main()
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798198143Z [34m│[0m          File "/workspace/manage.py", line 18, in main
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798200589Z [34m│[0m            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798203443Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798206846Z [34m│[0m            utility.execute()
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798209369Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798211755Z [34m│[0m            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798214609Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
2024-05-19T09:25:03.798216860Z [34m│[0m            self._setup(name)
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799020743Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799034752Z [34m│[0m            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799038539Z [34m│[0m                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799041885Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799045136Z [34m│[0m            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799048626Z [34m│[0m                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799067534Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799071440Z [34m│[0m            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799073707Z [34m│[0m                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799076220Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799078580Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799080861Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799083140Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799086719Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799090117Z [34m│[0m          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799093359Z [34m│[0m          File "/workspace/sportivisionWeb_app/settings.py", line 33, in <module>
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799096544Z [34m│[0m            GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799099661Z [34m│[0m                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799103361Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 258, in from_service_account_file
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799106716Z [34m│[0m            info, signer = _service_account_info.from_filename(
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799109913Z [34m│[0m                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799113585Z [34m│[0m          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 78, in from_filename
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799118119Z [34m│[0m            with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799121467Z [34m│[0m                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-19T09:25:03.799125456Z [34m│[0m        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/sincere-burner-419722-ee69790d1073.json'
2024-05-19T09:25:03.823627176Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828174062Z [34m│[0m  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828194400Z [34m│[0m        See traceback above for details.
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828197504Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828200059Z [34m│[0m        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828203156Z [34m│[0m        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828205417Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828208591Z [34m│[0m           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828210887Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.828213276Z [34m│[0m        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
2024-05-19T09:25:03.829240927Z [34m│[0m [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build: exit status 1
2024-05-19T09:25:03.943960252Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.947203391Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.947427275Z [34m│[0m For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2024-05-19T09:25:03.947435400Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.947439195Z [34m│[0m    Python  v4.242.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-python
2024-05-19T09:25:03.947615945Z [34m│[0m 
2024-05-19T09:25:03.955948248Z [34m│[0m [31m ✘ build failed[0m

I try to configure build command like a start.sh to create the file but the build command is run after the build.

You should be able to build your app with environment variable dependencies and then include the environment variable value (Service Account key) at runtime in the app's spec How to use environment variables
